# Hash Key for Facebook Login on PhoneGap Build & OAuth URL for PhoneGap Hybrid App Facebook Login

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, oauth, phonegap-build

I have a website and also need to run it on app via Phonegap Build. I need to implement facebook login so I have put the following code in my mywebsite.com/login.html file, now on running this file on browser it gives error :

**login.html**

```
   <html lang="en">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<title>Login  </title>


 <script type="text/javascript">


  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : 'my-app-id',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v2.12'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){

     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}

     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;

     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";

     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));



        function login()
        {


            facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile", "email"], function(result){

                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

                facebookConnectPlugin.api("/me?fields=email,name,picture",["public_profile", "email"], function(userData){ 

                    alert(JSON.stringify(userData));

                },function(error){
                    alert(JSON.stringify(errror));
                });




            },function(error){
                alert(JSON.stringify(errror));
            });



        } 




 </script>
```

```
<button class="loginbtn" onclick="login();">Login with Facebook</button>
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: facebookConnectPlugin is not defined at
>   login() at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Question 1 : Do I need to include some sdk files to eliminate this error ?

Question 2 : What is the URL which needs to be saved in Developer Console ?

I put this code in the index.html file of PhoneGap Build & got the APK, on execution, it opens the Native Facebook App for Login, I logged in but after logging me in it says that **Given URL not allowed.**

What is the URL which I need to allow on my developers console of Facebook. Also how will I send the fetched details to my online server if I use this method. In this method my login UI will reside in PhoneGap local files & rest of the website code will be online on my web server. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You need the cordova plugin cordova-plugin-facebook5.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-facebook5.

This allows you to integrate into the actual facebook app on the phone, and fall back to the web.

Comment: : How do I go to next page if login is successful in my local PhoneGap app ? I am not using jquery mobile, is there any other way out?

Comment: You should get a response from the actual plugin. facebookConnect.Plugin.login(["public_profile"], function (deets){}, failure)